# Почему возникла ошибка в обновлении отчета Power BI?

Tags: диаграммы, powerbi

На основе БД postgresql построен дэшборд в Power BI.
При обновлении локально - все данные в дэшборде обновляются, но при размещении его в проде и выставлении расписания обновления, после ожидаемого обновления выводится следующая ошибка:

> Состояние
> Several errors occured during data refresh. Please try again
> later or contact your administrator

```
SessionID: 35e5304a-6b12-4cdf-b1fb-8c123456993d

[0] -1055784932: Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.. Key = [Schema = "bi_reports", Item = "bi_example"]. Table = #table({"Name", "Data", "Schema", "Item", "Kind"}, {}). ;The key didn't match any rows in the table.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

[1] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

[2] -1055129594: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.
```

Пробовал заново разместить дэш, но это не помогло.